# Is there a ways to make google store coordinates in the android map?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm in the middle of developing android app using google map. My question is - how to store coordinates with google map and display them later on? I know how to use canvas, how to draw it etc. but I want to store those coordinates with google map - just like with the google maps feature on internet. When I log in I can see points I've put on the map straight away. Can someone please tell me how to do that? There must be a way. Any answers greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You store the coordinates, along with any other descriptive information, in some form of persistent storage.

From the [Android Application Framework FAQ](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/framework.html):

**Persistent Objects**

Even while an application appears to continue running, the system may choose to kill its process and restart it later. If you have data that you need to persist from one activity invocation to the next, you need to represent that data as state that gets saved by an activity when it is informed that it might go away.

For sharing complex persistent user-defined objects, the following approaches are recommended:

- Application Preferences
- Files
- contentProviders
- SQLite DB

If the shared data needs to be retained across points where the application process can be killed, then place that data in persistent storage like Application Preferences, SQLite DB, Files or ContentProviders. Please refer to the [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for further details on how to use these components.